# Create dataframe of multiple appended arrays using for loop or nested loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe that for each row, I want to create list of 100 numbers (step 1), then multiply these lists together (step 2) and finally have a dataframe with the result (step 3). I can do this for one row but I'm struggling with how to write a for loop to do this for all of the rows. Using a nested loop or another method would also be fine.

Starting with the dataframe, `orig`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

orig = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 2.09328, 11.4043282, 0.1, 1.1], ['b', 5.985439, 6.59949, 0.3, 0.19], ['c', 8.5543045, 9.5402459, 0.09, 1.2]]),
                   columns=['site', 'x_min', 'x_max','y_min','y_max'])
orig = orig.set_index('site')
```

I want to create two new variables, `x` and `y` for each row in `orig`:

```py
# Step 1: Create two new variables x and y for each row. For example, for the first row, site a, this would look like this:
x_a = np.linspace(2.09328,11.4043282,100)
y_a = np.linspace(0.1, 1, 100)
```

Then for each row, I want to multiply the `x` and `y` variables along with a constant `z`:

```py
# Step 2: For each site, multiply the x and y arrays together with another variable z
z = 24
pd.DataFrame(x_a*y_a*24)
```

And then for Step 3 I want to have a dataframe where each column name is the row in `orig` (so, "a", "b", "c") and the rows are the product from the previous calculation, so x*y*z. The shape for this final dataframe should be three columns by 100 rows.

All I have so far is this and it's not working too well for me:

```py
# So far all I have for step 1 is this:
xs = []
ys = []

#for each row in dataframe
for i in range(orig.shape[0]):
    row = orig.iloc[i:,]
    
    _xs = np.linspace(row['x_min'], row['x_max'], 100)
    _ys = np.linspace(row['y_max'], row['y_min'],100)
    print(_xs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With below data frame where `x` and `y` columns are float fields (unlike posted data frame that cast all values in `np.array` as string due to `site` values):

```
orig = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2.09328, 11.4043282, 0.1, 1.1], 
                              [5.985439, 6.59949, 0.3, 0.19], 
                              [8.5543045, 9.5402459, 0.09, 1.2]]),
                    index=['a', 'b', 'c'],
                    columns=['x_min', 'x_max','y_min','y_max']).rename_axis('site')
```

consider a list comprehension followed by transpose of rows/columns, and renaming columns.

```
final_df = (pd.DataFrame([np.linspace(orig.loc[s, 'x_min'], orig.loc[s, 'x_max'],100) *
                          np.linspace(orig.loc[s, 'y_min'], orig.loc[s, 'y_max'],100) * z
                                  for s in orig.index.values])
              .transpose()
              .set_axis(orig.index.values, axis='columns', inplace=False)
           )

final_df.shape
# (100, 3)

final_df.head(10)
#            a          b          c
# 0   5.023872  43.095161  18.477298
# 1   5.779856  42.980042  20.803375
# 2   6.581441  42.864592  23.134811
# 3   7.428627  42.748812  25.471608
# 4   8.321413  42.632701  27.813764
# 5   9.259799  42.516259  30.161280
# 6  10.243786  42.399486  32.514155
# 7  11.273373  42.282382  34.872391
# 8  12.348561  42.164948  37.235986
# 9  13.469349  42.047182  39.604941
```

Comment: Hi @Parfait, thank you so much. This answer was great and worked perfectly when I applied it to my actual data. I'm always struggling with list comprehensions to solve my problems. Do you have any recommendations for reading/material that could help me improve this? Or will time and experience just lead me to where I want to be.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! I say simply practice even with trial and error. Anything you need returned in a list or dictionary over an iterable can be written with list or dict comprehension. When you have to initialize a list/dict and in a `for` loop `append` or assign, `=`, items, then a comprehension can be used.